# Cordova Dynamic / Random Splashscreen

Tags: android, ios, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

Every-time when the app load, it shows the same boring splash screen. Is it possible to have dynamic splash screen images that will show randomly every-time when the app starts? It would be very useful for us to show some tips & info about the app when loading.

Comment: Not with the currect plugin, but you can create your own plugin. On iOS the launch image can't be dynamic, the current plugin shows the same image you use for launch image. If you want a dynamic image on iOS you should show a white or black launch image and then your dynamic image as splash image